# JAXB Unmarshalling with MTOM

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, mtom, apache-tomee

I have a problem unmarshalling MTOM for a RetrieveDocumentSetResponse, which is part of XDS.

In my generated JAXB files, I simply have an element document which is a `byte[]`.
After I perform the usual `unmarshalling` steps:

```
final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType.class);
final Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

final JAXBElement<RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType> rdsJaxb = u.unmarshal(
                    soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007", "RetrieveDocumentSetResponse").item(0),
                    RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType.class);
final RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType rdsResp = rdsJaxb.getValue();
```

My document is empty: `rdsResp.getDocument().length == 0`.

In checking with `TCPMonitor` I see that the document is getting sent over the line, so the error must be somewhere in the unmarshalling.

I have tried using a `DataHandler` instead of a byte[] and annotating the document variable with an `@XMLMimeType` annotation to no avail. I'm using TomEE as my deployment target which uses the RI version of JAXB I believe.

I'm also using regular dispatching for the web service call, making sure to enable MTOM:

```
final Service repoService;
final QName repoPort = new QName(XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_NAMESPACE, XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_PORT);
        if (XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_WSDL == null) {
            repoService = Service.create(new QName(XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_NAMESPACE, XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_SERVICE));
        } else {
            repoService = Service.create(XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_WSDL, new QName(XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_NAMESPACE,
                    XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_SERVICE));
        }
        repoService.addPort(repoPort, SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING, XdsProperties.XDS_REPOSITORY_ENDPOINT);
final MTOMFeature mtomFt = new MTOMFeature(true);
REPOSITORY_DISPATCH = repoService.createDispatch(repoPort, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE, addrFt, mtomFt);
```

And I even do:

```
REPOSITORY_DISPATCH.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, soapAction);       
final SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) REPOSITORY_DISPATCH.getBinding();         
binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);
```

I'm really not sure what's going wrong or what I'm supposed to do since no exceptions are being thrown, the document is just always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for attachments to be resolved during a JAXB unmarshal an `AttachmentUnmarshaller` needs to be set on the `Unmarshaller`.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#setAttachmentUnmarshaller%28javax.xml.bind.attachment.AttachmentUnmarshaller%29

When JAXB is leveraged under the covers by JAX-WS this is handled automatically.  If you are interacting with the XML directly you will need to implement and set the `AttachmentUnmarshaller` your self.  Below is a link to an example that will help:

- [What's the most standard Java way to store raw binary data along with XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315968/whats-the-most-standard-java-way-to-store-raw-binary-data-along-with-xml/5316087#5316087)