# Not able to extract cid/attachment/binary data from WebService call |Spring Cloud feign |Apach cxf|Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, cxf, spring-cloud-feign

> I have a PersonProxy which contains one method which invokes third party webservice.
> AttachmentResponse is a wsdl generated class
> Decoder is configured to decode the response into Wsdl generated class.
> I have written an api which calls PersonProxy class method to get the response.
> While unmarshalling in decoder, in AttachmentResponse _return is coming as null.
> Not able to fetch binary data in _return variable.Please help on this

```
  @FeignClient(name = "PersonProxyWebService", url = "${url}",configuration = ServiceConfiguration.class)
    public interface PersonProxy {
    
        @GetMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
        AttachmentResponse getResultAttachment(Long attachementId);
    }

  


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "attachmentResponse", propOrder = {
        "_return"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "attachmentResponse")
    public class AttachmentResponse {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "return")
        protected byte[] _return;
        //getter and setter 
    }

 

   public class SOAPDecoder implements Decoder {
    
      @Override
      public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
        if (response.status() == 404)
          return Util.emptyValueOf(type);
        if (response.body() == null)
          return null;
        while (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
          ParameterizedType ptype = (ParameterizedType) type;
          type = ptype.getRawType();
        }
        if (!(type instanceof Class)) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
              "SOAP only supports decoding raw types. Found " + type);
        }
    
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response.body().asInputStream())) {
         Optional<String> soapEnvOpt= scanner.findAll(pattern).map(f->f.group(1)).findFirst();
          if(soapEnvOpt.isPresent()) {
              SOAPMessage message =  MessageFactory.newInstance(soapProtocol).createMessage(null,new ByteArrayInputStream(soapEnvOpt.get().getBytes()));
              if (message.getSOAPBody() != null) {
                if (message.getSOAPBody().hasFault()) {
                  throw new SOAPFaultException(message.getSOAPBody().getFault());
                }
               
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContextFactory.createUnmarshaller((Class<?>) type);
                if (this.useFirstChild) {
                  return unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild());
                } else {
                  return unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
                }
              }
          }
        } catch (SOAPException | JAXBException e) {
          throw new DecodeException(response.status(), e.toString(), response.request(), e);
        } finally {
          if (response.body() != null) {
            response.body().close();
          }
        }
        return Util.emptyValueOf(type);
    
      }
    }
```

> > > On debug mode response is coming like this but return field is coming >>>null in Wsdl generated class .
> > > How to map contentId (cid) on client side to extract binary data?

```
  <soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <ns2:attachmentResponse>
                xmlns:ns2="http://mscs.com/emr">
                <return>
                    <xop:Include
                        xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:180aba29-24c2-44cd-b0a5-63a3b5ff4189-5@cxf.apache.org"/>
                    </return>
                </ns2:attachmentResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `SOAPDecoder` in OpenFeign does not handle MTOM correctly. To make it work, 2 changes need to be implemented:

- propagate `MimeHeaders` to the `SOAPMessage`, as described in this Github issue https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/1732
- add an `AttachmentUnmarshaller` to the JAXB `Unmarshaller`, as described here [Unmarshalling XOP with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407360/unmarshalling-xop-with-jaxb/24417032#24417032)