# what is the use of @PersistentContext and @Stateless in JAX-RS?

Tags: rest, annotations, jax-rs

I am fairly new to using JAX-RS. The tutorials I went through made it really simple by showing how to make `GET/POST/DELETE` requests. But did not go through advanced annotations. Now I am reading the Java EE 7 essentials book. I am confused with many new annotations that I see here. I tried to find the utility of these annotations. but I did not understand. I have always found SO answers to be easily understandable for beginners.

Here is the code from [github](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs/db-access/src/main/java/org/javaee7/jaxrs/dbaccess):

**Employee.Java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REST_DB_ACCESS")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e")
})
@XmlRootElement
public class Employee implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column(length=40)
private String name;
public Employee() { }
public Employee(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
return name + " " + id;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (null == obj)
return false;
if (!(obj instanceof Employee))
return false;
Employee that = (Employee)obj;
if (that.name.equals(this.name) && that.id == this.id)
return true;
else
return false;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name);
}
}
```

**EmployeeResource.Java**

```
 @Path("employee")
    @Stateless
    public class EmployeeResource {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Employee[] get() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Employee.findAll", Employee.class).getResultList().toArray(new Employee[0]);
    }
    }
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}
```

1. What is the use of `EmployeeResource` class? Is that a design pattern? I could have done this using DAO access in  `get()` method?
2. what does `@PersistentContext` and `@Stateless` mean? I did search for these the annonations in google. but I am not convinced that I understood it
3. what is the use of `Application` Class? Is it always needed? In the tutorial I went through, no mention was made about `Application` class. On the same token, what does `@ApplicationPath` annotation mean?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *What is the use of EmployeeResource class? Is that a design pattern? I could have done this using DAO access in get() method?*

   The `EmployeeResource` class represents your RESTful service.  From it you are going to expose different methods using `@GET`, `@PUT`, `@POST`, `@DELETE` etc.
2. *what does @PersistentContext and @Stateless mean? I did search for these the annonations in google. but I am not convinced that I understood it*

   `@PersistenceContext` is a JPA annotation.  JPA covers the conversion of database data to/from a Java domain model.  Since RESTful services generally represent CRUD (create, read, update, delete) operations with Java domain objects as parameters it is very convenient to use JPA to do the actual persistence operations.

   `@Stateless` is a EJB (Session Bean) annotation. It means that the bean cannot maintain any sort of state between calls.
3. *what is the use of Application Class? Is it always needed? In the tutorial I went through, no mention was made about Application class. On the same token, what does @ApplicationPath annotation mean?*

   It is a useful way to pull in pieces that aren't annotated with `@Provider`.  One useful annotation is the `@ApplicationPath` annotation (see:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html).  This sets the first part part of the path, this is followed by the `@Path` set on the resource class, which is finally followed by the `@Path` set on the REST operation itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. what happens if I don't specify `@Stateless` Annotation in the above class?

Comment: Also, the `Application` subclass with the `@ApplicationPath` is mandatory in a JavaEE6 or 7 environment, as it will 'activate' the JAX-RS support. An alternative to this Java class is to declare a <servlet-mapping> in the `web.xml` file.

Comment: It is possible also to annotate the resource class itself with `@ApplicationPath` and have it implement `Application` see [example](https://www.voxxed.com/blog/2015/02/building-a-simple-app-using-java-ee-7-with-angularjs-part-one/)